# Reading XML data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json

I want to pull data from Google's Suggest API and display it in my page *(probably via the append function)*. I am confident with parsing JSON but not XML and as far as I can see Google do not offer this API in JSON.

How can I do this? **Or, does anyone know how I can access this API in JSON? If anyone does that would be awesome!**

The API address is: http://google.com/complete/search?q=google&output=toolbar

My current code is:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://google.com/complete/search?q=google&output=toolbar",
            dataType: "xml",
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('toplevel').each(function(){
                    var title = $(this).find('suggestion').text();
                    $('<b>'+title+'</b>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                });
            }
        });
```

And the error I am getting is: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://google.com/complete/search?q=wixiy&output=toolbar. Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: You can `.find()` data in an XML document exactly as you would in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, the API does not support `JSON`, so you can't do it just in javascript as it won't allow cross-domain requests by default. So, you will need an intermediate server-side page like a `PHP` file, which does the xml request from google and pass the xml to you.

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getData.php?q=google&output=toolbar",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
        $(xml).find("CompleteSuggestion").each(function(){
            var suggestion = $( this ).find( 'suggestion' ).attr( 'data' );
            var num_queries = $( this ).find( 'num_queries' ).attr( 'int' );
            alert( suggestion + ' has ' + num_queries + ' queries.' );
        });
    }
});
```

**PHP (getData.php)** - This file is on the same server

```
$query = $_GET[ 'q' ];
$out = $_GET[ 'output' ];

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo file_get_contents('http://google.com/complete/search?q='.$query.'&output='.$out);
```

...or else, you can directly `json_encode` it and send JSON to your script, which can be easily parsed as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Won't this solution be quite slow?

Comment: I don't think so, but can't say for sure. You test it in your environment and decide for yourself. Works fine for me on my m/c.

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing, jQuery **CAN** parse XML. Check out [the $.ajax docs page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - it says

> **converters (added 1.5)**
>   A map of dataType-to-dataType converters. Each converter's value is a function that returns the transformed value of the response.

So your ajax call should just set that setting.

```
$.ajax({ url: "apiUrl", converters: "text xml" });
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but I get an error in my Debugging Console. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm... you definitely shouldn't :D Well, could you post your whole call to $.ajax() and the error itself?

Comment: Probably the usual cross-site AJAX failure.

Comment: @Blazemonger It was a cross-domain AJAX failure I got so I ended up ditching the code. Any ideas?

Comment: Set the crossDomain setting of the $.ajax call to "true"? And/or... $.ajax({ xhrFields: { withCredentials: true } });

Comment: @Balkanski I have never come across that before; how do I use it?

Comment: Try this out:
`$.ajax({ crossDomain: true, xhrFields: { withCredentials: true } });`
See if it works and if it doesn't, try setting both values to either true or false in all 4 possible combinations.

Comment: @Balkanski I have just tried that and I am getting the same error. Shall I post my code?

Comment: The usual solution is to write a short server-side script of your own that will read that cross-domain XML and re-output it from your own domain.

Answer (score 0):

You may use DomParser
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingXMLSource, "application/xml");
```